# Check for double extensions in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am uploading files from flutter app to server. Before uploading the file i want to check if file is malicious file containing double extensions in file name like (.pdf.jpg) or (.xls.jpg). How can i do it.

Comment: you should use regex

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/extension.html